# Want to understand this slick proof of Green's Theorem using Stoke's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

[image]

I saw this short proof of Green's theorem using the general Stokes' theorem, which I suppose refers to($\oint_{\partial D}\omega=\int_D\,d\omega$).

I would like to understand it better, as I find it pretty amazing.

However I am stuck on the following steps:

Q1) Why is $$d\omega=\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx+\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}dx\wedge dy$$

Q2) How to understand the final step $$\int_D\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx+\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}dx\wedge dy=\iint_D(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y})dxdy$$

I have no background knowledge on differential forms / exterior derivatives. Is there an intuitive / semirigorous way to understand the above two steps?

Thanks!

I always had trouble remembering Green's Theorem, I think understanding this proof may be a good way to memorize it.

Comment: Surely understanding a proof using differential forms requires *some* background knowledge of differential forms...

Comment: I see... It is more complicated than I thought it was. I thought there might be interpretations like $d\omega$ is a small piece of $\omega$, something like $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ in calculus.

Comment: There are such interpretations, but of course one needs to know something about the properties of differential forms that are used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q1: see [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) and note that $\omega=Ldx+Mdy$. Then you have to skip ahead, take a look at skew-symmetry, to see that what you're left with is the expression you give, since $dx\wedge dx=dy\wedge dy=0$ by the skew-symmetry.

For Q2: see [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) and control+f 'skew-symmetry'. Note that the passage in notation from $\int$ to $\int\int$ is just convention; when working with forms one always only writes a single $\int$ sign.

I'll try to make it more intuitive. Basically switching from $dx\wedge dy$ to $dy\wedge dx$ switched the orientation. Since switching the orientation of the volume over which you integrate gives a minus sign:
$$\int_D\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx+\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}dx\wedge dy=\int_D\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)dx\wedge dy$$
And the RHS is equal, just by definition, to $\iint_D(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y})dxdy$.

Comment: I see... I have gained some knowledge from your answer. Thanks.